# Minimize on close

Tags: c#, minimize

In short, I have this:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
```

And it's not working (program closes when pushed "X", instead of my destination - minimizing it); what could be the problem?

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false; // is used because app goes to system tray and it doesn't need to be showed in taskbar.
```

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;` ?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and step through the debugger to see if your code to minimize is being called? As Chris mentioned below, it is possible that the code in the "If" statement is not executing

Comment: Jon, I edited my post, Soner I also want it not to be showed in taskbar (as I use Icontray on minimize).

Answer (score 2):

Why bother testing to see what state the window is currently in?

Just set `e.Cancel` to `true` and set the state to minimized.

=== update ===

I created a new Windows Forms project (tested both 4.0 and 3.5 frameworks, using VS2010 and VS2012).

From there I added the notify icon to Form1 and set the doubleclick event (code below) and the icon to some random icon file I had.  I also set the forms formclosing event (code below):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e ) {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseEventArgs e ) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Then I ran the project.  When I clicked the close button, the form was hidden.  When I double clicked the notify icon it came back.  I'm on Windows 7, but that shouldn't matter.

Now, I did find that if I made Form1 a child form, then some weirdness occurred.  But I'm not entirely sure that's what you are doing.

Comment: True, removed the if (updated code), still not work. On pushing close button app actualy closes..

Comment: @Tautvydas: I just put together a tiny sample project.  The only thing it had was a single form and a formclosing event.  The event only contained `e.Cancel = true;` and `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimuzed;`  When I tried to close, it minimized as expected.  Are you sure the `ShowInTaskbar=false;` part isn't making you think it closed?  You might want to drop that particular code line.

Comment: I just tried it in same way and it closed as it is closing in main app. Could it be connected with .net framework version? (mine is 3.5)

Comment: Still same, I use Visual Studio 2008. Doesn't work at the moment I changed at form properies value of ControlBox to false, which removes windown control buttons, still there is problem with alt+f4. Could it be problem that I have changed some settings in form properties?

Comment: @Tautvydas: Just tried alt+f4, behaves as expected.  I don't have 2008 to test with.  Although I don't see why that would matter.  Sorry out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can't have this.ShowInTaskbar set to false *and* have it minimized; in order to do what you're trying to do you'd need this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

Then in whatever you're using to bring the form back to standard view, you would just put:

```
this.Visible = true;
```

If you're still looking for the minimize animation, just minimize the form before you set the visibility.

Comment: Technically you can.  The form just completely hides itself though.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought I had remembered it causing odd problems for me at one point- I guess I was remembering incorrectly :)